# Matplotlib Table Bbox - how to control position and style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can add a table to an axes like this:

```
from matplotlib.table import table

stats_table = table(ax5, cellText=cell_text,
                  rowLabels=rows,
                  colLabels=cols,
                  bbox = [0.1, 0, 0.9, 0.8])
```

I can use bbox to specify it's position but how do I then style the bbox?

In other examples I've seen for styling a bbox it uses something like

```
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="rarrow,pad=0.3", fc="cyan", ec="b", lw=2)
```

But how can I use that at the same time as defining the position of the bbox?

Comment: If you saw something you quote here, please link to it. I strongly doubt that it was used for a table though, as the table does not have any stylable box around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may iterate over the table cells and set the properties, like colors and linewidth. The table does not have any box around it, hence you cannot set any box style.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.table import table

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

stats_table = table(ax, cellText=np.random.randint(1,9,(5,2)),
                  rowLabels=list("ABCDE"),
                  colLabels=list("PU"),
                  bbox = [0.1, 0, 0.9, 0.8])

for key, cell in stats_table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_linewidth(2)
    cell.set_edgecolor("b")
    cell.set_facecolor("cyan")

plt.show()
```